# What is the term called for the sudden blackout before the suspense scene?

Tags: film-techniques

Mostly in the cartoons and in some TV series or movies sometimes the screen turned black mid-between a sudden surprise scene, which impacts great to maintaining goosebumps. The last i noticed this is in the [Under the Dome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_%28TV_series%29). Is there a specific term or name for it?

Comment: It may also be that the U.S. use more frequent (but shorter) commercial breaks and thus what you are experiencing might have originally been a fade out for a commercial (at a very exciting part, to keep the audience hooked, of course) that was removed in your version.

Comment: @ChristianRau it appears intentional to me and specially seen in various American cartoons and non American too but some American cartoons doesn't have this blackout at all. I might required few more example i think.

Comment: I noticed that in the [Teenage Mutant Hero Turtles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_%281987_TV_series%29) series (at least in Germany). But I always thought it should "resuce" or calm down the kids so that they are not too scared in thrilling scenes.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Is it a cut that occurred for a commercial break when it was originally broadcast (that never happens because you're watching it on Netflix or DVD)?

Comment: @BenPlont i am watching it one broadcasting channels BIG CBS network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but it's just called "cut to black" (as opposed to the more traditional "fade to black"). Sometimes things are called exactly what you'd expect.

If a screenwriter wanted to emphasize that the picture is to remain black for awhile, usually the script would describe something audio-only, e.g.:

```
Looking down into the grave, we see the coffin lid close over our very-much-alive hero.

                                                                                   CUT TO:
BLACK.

Heavy breathing. Scratching sounds. . . .
```

And then in editing usually the big suspenseful music cues are added.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably thinking of a [Smash Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_cut). In effect, this is a 'cut' (the same as if you were watching a film and the film goes from one scene to another), but is much more abrupt.

Comment: +1 for the response but from wiki description Smash Cut is like switching of scene unexpectedly but i am referring to blackout between same scene like a pause with black screen.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a name for that sort of thing - I think it's just something that directors or screenwriters add by themselves. I recall a film Zero Effect where the some scenes kind of faded to black/white, then back a second later as if it were a cut - which, I suppose, it technically was...