# What is the reason for these 10-second gaps?

Tags: arrowverse, supergirl

I've been watching [Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(U.S._TV_series)) for a while now, and something got me wondering. Why are there 10-second gaps between most scenes (not all)? I encountered the same thing years ago with [No Ordinary Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Ordinary_Family), which was also produced by [Greg Berlanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Berlanti). At first I thought it was a Berlanti thing, but there are so many TV shows by him. So, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Do you mean [What is the term called for the sudden blackout before the suspense scene?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-is-the-term-called-for-the-sudden-blackout-before-the-suspense-scene), then it will be a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe if you point out a few scenes, it could be easier to answer, but do not forget that TV shows are cut with ads. So after the ads end, it may be interesting to "restaure" the ambiance.

Comment: How are you watching the show? Could these blackouts be where commercial breaks would otherwise be? Is it a cut to ads?

Comment: Hrm, never thought of that. I'll try to find a website I can watch it in full and confirm. Then again, it never happens in Arrow or The Flash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what you're talking about here. I'm going to assume that you, like I, sometimes watch an MP4 file (or similar) that you have come by through a non-traditional DVR method. And that it's on these files where you're observing the long black gaps.

The long black gaps appear to occur at the time that the commercial breaks would have been inserted when the show was originally aired. I think the next question is, if the process or agent involved in creating the MP4 file had the intelligence to remove the commercials, then why didn't it also remove the weirdly long black silence?

Comment: If the process or agent involved in creating the MP4 file had the intelligence to remove the commercials, then why didn't it also remove the weirdly long black silence?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. It's something I've wondered myself throughout the whole season.

Comment: Still, I keep wondering why the same thing doesn't happen on Arrow, The Flash or Legends of Tomorrow. I've only seen it on No Ordinary Family and Supergirl.

Comment: Because the cutting for commercials is done by a different company. Super girl aired on a different channel than the other three.